# How to Validate json against jsonschema in flask?

Tags: python, json, flask

Is there any functionality support by any python library where we can pass one argument is jsonschema and second is json and validate it and return True or False? I dont have any control on how the jsonschema will be?

example:

```
json:
{
  "id":1,
  "name":"intel"
}
```

using (https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-json-to-schema-converter) this to generate jsonschema.

```
jsonschema:
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "id",
    "name"
  ]
}
```

if i will use https://jsonschema.net/ to generate jsonschema then

```
jsonschema:
{
"definitions": {},
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
"$id": "http://example.com/root.json",
"type": "object",
"title": "The Root Schema",
"required": [
 "id",
 "name"
 ],
"properties": {
        "id": {
       "$id": "#/properties/id",
       "type": "integer",
       "title": "The Id Schema",
       "default": 0,
       "examples": [
         1
       ]
     },
     "name": {
       "$id": "#/properties/name",
       "type": "string",
       "title": "The Name Schema",
       "default": "",
       "examples": [
        "intel"
       ],
       "pattern": "^(.*)$"
     }
   }
}
```

So the user can take any website to generate jsonschema and store into db through post api. 
And there is another post api where input json will validate against jsonschema which is stored by user.
How to solve this scenarios ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

I got how to work around it. Am using jsonschema library for validating .
from jsonschema import validate
using this validate() which will take json and jsonschema and validate them.